# findOne() by an element of an object that resides inside a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i don't know if it is possible or not , if it is, can anyone please tell me how can i find a user, created from this

```
 var user = User({
        'Name': req.body.dName,
        'Email': req.body.email,
        'Password': hash,
        'Verification':{"status":"not_varified","verification_id":+rand}
    });
```

using `verification_id`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the dot notation for this.

```
User.findOne({"Verification.verification_id":your_id});
```